# pycurl equivalent of "curl --data-binary"

Tags: python, pycurl

I'd like to know the equivalent of this curl command in pycurl:

```
curl --data-binary @binary_data_file.bin 'http://server/myapp/method'
```

Note: The above curl statement uses the POST method. I need to use this for compatibility with my server script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `requests` library is meant to keep things like this simple:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://server/myapp/method', data={'aaa': 'bbb'})
```

Or depending on how the receiving end expects data:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://server/myapp/method',
    data=file('binary_data_file.bin','rb').read())
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, the fact that you've suggested an alternative module to pycurl that will allow such pythonic one-liners makes for a better answer than an actual pycurl implementation.

Answer (score 2):

From libcurl, setopt(...) try this option:

**CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE**

*If you want to post data to the server without letting libcurl do a strlen() to measure the data size, this option must be used. When this option is used you can post fully binary data, which otherwise is likely to fail. If this size is set to -1, the library will use strlen() to get the size.*

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDSIZE